# HTML5 Numeric input in MS Edge appends the placeholder text

Tags: html, placeholder, microsoft-edge

An invalid numeric input in ME Edge entry just get appended,

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Value" />
```

On entering non-numeric, or entering a minus appends with the placeholder text:

[image]

How this can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug reported on the [Edge issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4546283/) as "Incorrect behaviour of placeholder text in a text field 'number' when typing letters".