# How can I remove the Placeholder when the User Starts Typing ( Microsoft Edge )

Tags: php, input, microsoft-edge

I use the Following Code for the Input
I tested this in Chrome and it works, but when I use edge it doesnt remove the Placeholder ( on typing )

```
<div class="control-group input-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" name="telefonnummer" required="required" class="span4 offset8 required form-control col-md-offset-8 col-md-4" value="<?= $user->telefonnummer; ?>" placeholder="<?= translate('Telefonnummer'); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I dont use type="number" it works...
If there isnt a way to fix it, how can I only allow numbers on this Input?


**Screenshot of the Problem**
[image: problem]

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I am using Bootstrap. The Restriction of the Input Works in edge but doesnt remove the Placeholder when a User Starts typing in it ( only happens when using text not numbers)

Comment: Placeholders are managed automatically by the browser, I don't think there's any way for you to control this. It sounds like an Edge bug.

Comment: It removes the placeholder if you start typing a number, but if you type letters it keeps the placeholder after the typing. Definitely seems like a bug.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282429/html5-numeric-input-in-ms-edge-appends-the-placeholder-text which has a link to the bug tracker.